# Simple Inner product space Inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, inner-products

I need some help to prove that the following is false.

Let $V$ be an inner product space and $u,v,w$ be elements of $V$.

$$|\langle u,v\rangle | \leqslant||u|| + ||v||$$

I have tried using cauchy schwarz and finding a counter example, but am failing to do so.

Comment: Take $u=v$ for some $u$ whose norm is greater than $2$.

Comment: @user1551 I still don't understand how that is a counter example...

Comment: When $u=v$, can you express both sides of the inequality in terms of $\|u\|$?

Comment: @user1551 |||u||^2| <= 2||u|| but I don't understand what the LHS is.

Comment: Now what if $\|u\|>2$? E.g. what do you get when $\|u\|=3$?